# Set delegate for presentedViewController (e.g. not using segues)

Tags: swift, delegates, uikit

I'm trying to set a delegate for a `presentedViewController` from the `presentingViewController`.  Since I am not using segues to access the destination ViewController, I am having a hard time trying to set the destination ViewController's delegate.

I expect the declaration needs to happen here:

```
if inspiredActionChosen == "plan" {

        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "planMealNC")


        delegate?.passInspiredRecipeKey(sender: self, inspiredRecipeKey: "-L0ijpon2MDXxPmmw63M")
        print("PASSING")
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but `presentedViewController` does not have a member delegate. Is there another option to do this, other than employing segues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sort of confused by your question. All you want to do is pass a delegate to a forward view controller and the standard practice below doesn't work?

```
class PlanMealViewController: UIViewController {

    var presentingDelegate: ThePresentingViewController?

}

class ThePresentingViewController: UIViewController {

    func presentViewController() {

        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "planMealNC")
        viewController.presentingDelegate = self
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I expected to do from the start and I'm confused by this behaviour too! When I implement the code as you have above, I get an error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'`

Comment: When you created `presentingDelegate` in the presented view controller, did you save the project in Xcode before trying to call it in the push method? That property won't be available until you save the project first.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. It's a real riddle! since I'm using a UITableView `editActionForRowAt` segues don't work. I'm sure there is a way to do this, I'm just missing something obvious!

Comment: This ended up being the closest answer. The issue seems to be cause by the fact that both the `presentingViewController` and `presentedViewController` are not recognised correctly, so I had to refer to the second VC using the method above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a delegate function

```
 protocol presentingProtocol{

  func passInspiredRecipeKey(sender:UIViewController,inspiredRecipeKey:String)

}
```

prsesenting class with variable declared for protocol

```
class PresentingViewController: UIViewController {

 var presentingDelegate: presentingProtocol?

 }
```

presented class

```
class presentedViewController: UIViewController {

func presentViewController() {

    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "planMealNC") as! PresentingViewController
    controller.presentingDelegate = self
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, found this link. Not via delegates but adding an IBAction to move between storyboards without segues:
https://medium.com/@stasost/xcode-a-better-way-to-deal-with-storyboards-8b6a8b504c06